# What function argument property allows for this odd overloading?

Tags: php, arguments, overloading

I'm not sure what exactly this kind of parameter list behavior is called, so it's difficult to search for more info. I will draw an example:

```
function echoThis( $a=NULL, $b=NULL, $c=NULL )
{
    if( $a != NULL )
        echo "A is not NULL; it is: " . $a . "\n";
    if( $b != NULL )
        echo "B is not NULL; it is: " . $b . "\n";
    if( $c != NULL )
        echo "C is not NULL; it is: " . $c . "\n";

}

function echoThat( $a=NULL, $b=NULL, $c=NULL )
{
    if( $a != NULL )
        echo "A is not NULL; it is: " . $a . "\n";
    elseif( $b != NULL )
        echo "B is not NULL; it is: " . $b . "\n";
    elseif( $c != NULL )
        echo "C is not NULL; it is: " . $c . "\n";
    else
        echo "Huh?\n";

}

$a = "hello";
$b = "how are you";
$c = "goodbye";

echoThis( $a );
echoThis( $a, $b );
echoThis( $a, $b, $c );
echo "--------\n";
echoThat( $a );
echoThat( $a, $b );
echoThat( $a, $b, $c );
echo "--------\n";
echoThis( $a );
echoThis( $b, $a );
echoThis( $c, $b, $a );
echo "--------\n";
echoThat( $a );
echoThat( $b, $a );
echoThat( $c, $b, $a );
echo "--------\n";
echoThis( $a );
echoThis( $b );
echoThis( $c );
echo "--------\n";
echoThat( $a );
echoThat( $b );
echoThat( $c );

?>
```

So, no matter the order of the variables passed it will fill out the internal scoped variables as if the first was $a and second $b and last $c, but if only one argument is supplied, it somehow matches the variable name to the correct internally scoped variable. So if only $c is passed, it skips $a and $b and knows to assign it to $c.

```
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
B is not NULL; it is: how are you  
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
B is not NULL; it is: how are you  
C is not NULL; it is: goodbye  
--------  
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
--------  
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
A is not NULL; it is: how are you  
B is not NULL; it is: hello  
A is not NULL; it is: goodbye  
B is not NULL; it is: how are you  
C is not NULL; it is: hello  
--------  
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
A is not NULL; it is: how are you  
A is not NULL; it is: goodbye  
--------  
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
A is not NULL; it is: how are you  
A is not NULL; it is: goodbye  
--------  
A is not NULL; it is: hello  
A is not NULL; it is: how are you  
A is not NULL; it is: goodbye
```

What is this called, so that I can find more information? (Or is this considered a bad practice? The most insteresting to me are the middle two stanzas produce different results, and the last two all fire using the first if statement even the value in the variable is correctly mapped (i think).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php - See default function arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
function say($first_argument = null, $second_argument = null) {
     echo $first_argument;
     echo $second_argument;
}
```

then it doesn't matter what the variables are called outside of that function.  You could have

```
$random_variable = "hello";
$other_variable = " world";

say($random_variable, $other_variable);

//outputs "hello world"
```

This is the same as

```
say("hello", " world");
```

If you want to be able to refer to the variable by the name they were originally, you really can't.  You could pass in an array:

```
 function say($args) {
     extract($args);
     echo $a;
     echo $b;
 }

 $args = array('a' => 'hello', 'b' => ' world');
 say($args); //hello world
```

which will let you refer to the variable by their key in the array, in which case it will match them.  For example:

```
$args = array('b' => ' world', 'a' => ' hello');
say($args); //hello world.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing depends on the order of the function arguments, not the variable name. If your function definition is

```
function echoThis( $a=NULL, $b=NULL, $c=NULL ) {
   ...
}
```

and you call it as

```
echoThis($a);
```

then you will see the behaviour you would expect. However, if you were to call

```
echoThis($b);
```

then the parameter (in this case `$b`) will be mapped to the first argument to the function, which is refered to as variable `$a` while the function is executed. To achieve the kind of result you are expected, you would have to call

```
echoThis (null, $b)
```

Which will effectively disregard the first parameter.

See [php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as it should:

```
--------
this-a
A is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
this-ab
A is not NULL; it is: hello
B is not NULL; it is: how are you
--------
this-abc
A is not NULL; it is: hello
B is not NULL; it is: how are you
C is not NULL; it is: goodbye
--------
that-a
A is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
that-ab
A is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
that-abc
A is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
this-a
A is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
this-ba
A is not NULL; it is: how are you
B is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
this-cba
A is not NULL; it is: goodbye
B is not NULL; it is: how are you
C is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
that-a
A is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
that-ba
A is not NULL; it is: how are you
--------
that-cba
A is not NULL; it is: goodbye
--------
this-a
A is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
this-b
A is not NULL; it is: how are you
--------
this-c
A is not NULL; it is: goodbye
--------
that-a
A is not NULL; it is: hello
--------
that-b
A is not NULL; it is: how are you
--------
that-c
A is not NULL; it is: goodbye
```

Every single function is called properly, and there is no strangeness.  The first parameter that is passed will always be `$a`, the second will always be `$b`, and the third will always be `$c`.

In `this-cba` `A` becomes goodbye instead of hello.

In `that-cba` `A` becomes goodbye instead of hello.

In `that-b` `A` becomes `how are you`.  `$a` is not null, and it is echoed out first and the rest isn't.  In all these last ones (`this` and `that`) `A` is not null.  If it was assigning them to the proper variable based on the name, you would see `B` is not null or `C` is not null.